# Can't connect to my online database with PDO and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, pdo

i'm trying to upload my school project on my personal Aruba domain. I have uploaded all the file on the server and the site is working untill i try to connect to the online database i've uploaded. It gives me this

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

I'm using PDO to do the connection.

```
 $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=<ip_address>;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Database daemon running? Port open? Connection viable? One of other million possible things? Come on, we're not tech support. This is googlable and self-solvable.

Comment: there is a reason why i posted here, because on the internet nobody talks about this...

Comment: About your *"Instead of "localhost" there is the database ip"* - Why does the code you included contain `localhost`?

Comment: *"because on the internet nobody talks about this"* - [Oh, really?](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Connection+failed%3A+SQLSTATE%5BHY000%5D+%5B2002%5D+Can%27t+connect+to+local+MySQL+server+through+socket+%27%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fmysql%2Fmysql.sock%27&t=lm&atb=v112-6_g&ia=qa) < click that.

Comment: Cause i didn't want to show the ip (?)

Comment: All the solutions in the internet are for local databases, not online. I do not have access to mysql folders on the aruba machine, this is why i've asked .

Comment: *"All the solutions in the internet are for local databases, not online."* - I sincerely doubt that. I won't stay here any much longer. Voting to close.

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate. If the answers from the duplicate don't fully address your question please ask another question and provide more details.